# Перебор controls в c#

Tags: winforms, c#

Простая задача — перебрать все флажки в данной форме и данном табе и отметить их как не выбранные. 
Нашел на мой взгляд правильное решение:

```
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
               cb.Checked = false;
            }

        }
```

Но оно не работает! И я не понимаю почему. Смотрел отладчиком - cb = null. Почему так может быть? В какую сторону копать?..

Comment: если `cb == Null`, значит в `с` вовсе не `CheckBox`, посмотрите, какого оно типа

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему дело в рекурсии. Должно работать

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls) {
            this.UncheckAllCheckBoxes( control );
        }
    }

    private void UncheckAllCheckBoxes(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls) {
            this.UncheckAllCheckBoxes( c );
        }

        var cb = control as CheckBox;

        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            cb.Checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но мне помогли на stackowerflow. 
А дело было в том, что я просто не указал имя таба. Вот такая вот глупость.